# Docker with Svelte Hot Reload

Tags: docker, svelte, hot-reload

I try to use Docker with Svelte from this template: 
https://github.com/sveltejs/template 
I know it's deprecated, but my project is already longer under construction and right now we feel the urge to add Docker.

Setting everything up went well, but if I use my docker-compose during development I now have to run:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up -d
```

Is there any way to use hot reload as regular svelt allows it?

My project is structured like this:
| frontend 
| - src/
| - Dockerfile
| backend
| - src/
| - Dockerfile
| docker-compose.yml

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  frontend:
   # restart: always
    build: ./frontend
    ports: ["8080:8080"]
    command: npm start
    
  backend:
    restart: always
    build: ./backend
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
```

frontend dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
#RUN npm run build
ENV PORT=8080
EXPOSE 8080
```

Any tips? 
I tried to use

```
volumes:
    - ./frontend:/frontend
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: What happens when you change `#RUN npm run build` to `#RUN npm run dev`?

Comment: => [4/6] RUN npm i                 
 => [5/6] COPY . .                                                           
 => [6/6] RUN npm run dev -d                                                                                                                                                                  
 => => # > svelte-app@1.0.0 start
 => => # > sirv public --no-clear --host --dev
 => => #   Your application is ready~! 
 => => #   - Local:      http://0.0.0.0:8080
 => => #  LOGS

getting stuck at this point then

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with the host not being found. Might be the exotic port you're providing. When I work with SvelteKit, the dev runner loads on port 5173. My assumptions are that you're using SvelteKit and not merely Svelte, and that you've already tried to run the dev server outside of the docker container and had success with that. If my assumptions are correct, try changing your build config to make noise on port 8080, or change your docker compose/dockerfile to expose port 5173. What happens then?